# Is it possible to tangle Results block?

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

Is it possible to tangle `#+RESULTS:` block? For example,

```
#+BEGIN_SRC rst :tangle ./test.txt :noweb yes
<<Tangle_Test>>
#+END_SRC

#+BEGIN_SRC python :exports results :results output raw
print("Results")
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS: 
Results
```

And I want to tangle `#+RESULTS:` part, not the actual Python source code.

---

Following radebrecht's answer, here is a working example:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC rst :tangle  ./test.txt :noweb yes
<<Tangle_Test>>
#+END_SRC

#+BEGIN_SRC python :results output code :tangle no :results_switches ":tangle no :noweb-ref Tangle_Test"
print("Print Results")
#+END_SRC
```

If you evaluate the code block (`C-c C-c`), then the following `#+RESULTS` block will be generated:

```
#+RESULTS:
#+BEGIN_SRC python :tangle no :noweb-ref Tangle_Test
Print Results
#+END_SRC
```

Then you can tangle the file (`org-babel-tangle`) and the resulting `test.txt` will contain `Print Results` only.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the `:results` and `:results_switches`parameters:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC python :results output code :results_switches ":tangle test.py"
print("Results")
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
#+BEGIN_SRC python :tangle test.py
Results
#+END_SRC
```

Unfortunately this only seems to work with the resulting block using the same language as the code-generator. If you want to switch languages or use the results as data in another block, have a look at the `:var` parameter.

Comment: Thanks a lot - this works. I think using the same language is not a problem, as I can just use different file extension for the target file (e.g, `test.txt` instead of `test.py`).

Answer (score 5):

Actually it was explained in the documentation of [Noweb reference syntax](http://orgmode.org/manual/Noweb-reference-syntax.html#Noweb-reference-syntax) (I cannot believe I missed this):

> It is possible to include the results of a code block rather than the
>   body. This is done by appending parenthesis to the code block name
>   which may optionally contain arguments to the code block as shown
>   below.
>
> ```
>  <<code-block-name(optional arguments)>>
> ```

If you specify `<<code-block-name()>>`, it will evaluate the specified code block and tangle only the results.

Only caveat is that you have to use different `code-block-name` for the code blocks that you actually want to tangle the source. In that sense, radebrecht's answer is also good since you can use one name for all code blocks, you just need to specify `:results_switches` for the blocks which you want to tangle their results.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into a similar need but tangling wouldn't work as my block was actually returning a list of lists and only *displaying* it as an org table and - while tangling would write the s-expressions - I actually needed the org table itself.

It was a pretty simple emacs-lisp script however

```
#+begin_src emacs-lisp :results silent
  (save-excursion
    (org-babel-goto-named-result "cognitive-biases-table")
    (forward-line)
    (write-region (point) (org-babel-result-end) "./biases.org"))
#+end_src
```

In case anyone runs into this oddball need.